# Editing of array in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to edit my list in an array but it doesn't work.

I am trying the single input value update it works but I don't know how to
update the array.

why this method was not  working, and  give the solution for the array edit

I store the data from the array but it says [object object] what can I do?

```
state={
    name:'Ajith',
    name1: 'kumar',
    name2 : [],
    changeEdit:false
}

edit = () => {
    this.setState({
        changeEdit : !this.state.changeEdit
    });
    let array = {
        name : this.state.name,
        name1 : this.state.name1
    };
    let Name = this.state.name2;
    Name.push(array);
    this.setState({
        name2 : Name
    })
    console.log(this.state.name2)
}

update = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        changeEdit : !this.state.changeEdit,
        name : this.refs.Edit.value,
        name1 : this.refs.Edit1.value,
        name2 : this.refs.Edit2.value
    })

}

inputEditEvent = (e) => {
    return(
        <div


            <div>
                <input type="text" defaultValue={this.state.name} ref = "Edit" style={{height:'30px'}}/>
                <input type="text" defaultValue={this.state.name1} ref = "Edit1" style={{height:'30px'}}/>
                <input type="text" defaultValue={this.state.name2} ref = "Edit2" style={{height:'30px'}}/>
            </div>
            <div>    
                <Editings cancel={this.edit} update={this.update}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

editEvent = (e) => {
    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.edit}>
                Edit
            </button>
            <h2>
                {this.state.name}<br/>
                {this.state.name}<br/>
                <br/>
                {this.state.name}
            </h2>
        </div> 
    )
}
render()
{
    return this.state.changeEdit ?
    this.inputEditEvent() : this.editEvent()
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is not an **array**, is an **object**

```
let array = {
        name : this.state.name,
        name1 : this.state.name1
    };
```

**This** is an array

```
let array = [
        {name : this.state.name },
        {name1 : this.state.name1 },
    ];
```

Also notice setState is **async**:

```
this.setState({
        name2 : Name // next value
    })
console.log(this.state.name2) // will print previous value
```

**Correct** way to log state:

```
this.setState({
        name2 : Name // next state
    },
   () => console.log(this.state.name2) // next state
);
```

Comment: This is not an edit for your code, I'm pointing out a misunderstood of data types